# Why is the second list in this code printing three times?

Tags: python, string, list

I cannot figure out why the second list in this code (group2) is printing three times.  The first time it prints one string in the list, the second time it prints two strings, and the third time it prints three strings.  What confuses me, is that the first list in this code (group1) also printing its self 3 times, but it has three strings each time it prints.  Is there a way to print each list with all three strings, just one time?

```
def partition(x):
    group1 = []
    group2 = []
    for i in x:
        if i[0] >= "a" and i[0] <= "m":
            group1.append(i)
        else:
            group2.append(i)

            print(group1)
            print(group2)

list1 = ['andy', 'bob', 'marc', 'nick', 'paul', 'zac']

partition(list1)
```

THE SHELL OUTPUT:

```
 >>> 
['andy', 'bob', 'marc']
['nick']
['andy', 'bob', 'marc']
['nick', 'paul']
['andy', 'bob', 'marc']
['nick', 'paul', 'zac']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the print statements outside the for loop will get your job done, since you need to print the final lists only once.

```
def partition(x):
    group1 = []
    group2 = []
    for i in x:
        if i[0] >= "a" and i[0] <= "m":
            group1.append(i)
        else:
            group2.append(i)

    print(group1)
    print(group2)

list1 = ['andy', 'bob', 'marc', 'nick', 'paul', 'zac']

partition(list1)
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
['andy', 'bob', 'marc']
['nick', 'paul', 'zac']
```

Comment: That did it!!  Thank you!  Can you explain why?  I am not sure I understand why changing the indentation on both prints solved the issue.  Is it  because when they were intended forward into the loop, it would print every time the loop occurred, but when its indented to the same space as the loop, it only printed once the loop had gone through everything?

Comment: Yeah exactly, glad that you figured it by yourself @OmarN .

Answer (score 2):

Every time you find a name that doesn't belong in `group1`, you *print both groups*.

Your loop does this:

- `'andy'` starts with `a` so belongs in `group1`. Append it.
- `'bob'` starts with `b` so belongs in `group1`. Append it.
- `'marc'` starts with `m` so belongs in `group1`. Append it.
- `'nick'` starts with `n` so belongs in `group2`. Append it, **and print both lists**.
- `'paul'` starts with `p` so belongs in `group2`. Append it, **and print both lists**.
- `'zac'` starts with `z` so belongs in `group2`. Append it, **and print both lists**.

If you only wanted to print both lists once, at the end, *unindent* the two `print()` statements so they are no longer part of the loop:

```
for i in x:
    if i[0] >= "a" and i[0] <= "m":
        group1.append(i)
    else:
        group2.append(i)

print(group1)
print(group2)
```

Now the `print()` statements are executed only when the `for` loop completes.

Python code uses indentation to group statements; by giving the `print()` lines the same indentation as the lines belonging to the `else:` suite above it, they too were part of that suite, and are executed with it.

By reducing the indentation to match the `for` statement instead, they are executed sequentially to that statement, so after the loop has completed.

Comment: I see!  That makes sense now!  Is there a way to only get the function to print a list once?  I can only seem to get it to print three times.

Comment: @OmarN: what output did you expect instead?

Comment: @OmarN: perhaps you wanted to un-indent the `print()` statements so they are not part of the loop?

Comment: @Omar just put the print function outside the forloop.

Comment: I expected the answer that Anmol_uppal wrote.  Thank you guys for your help, I understand now!  @Martijn_Pieters, thank you for your breakdown!  I understand now.